# Shell loop calling sed command every iteration

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to use sed to get rid of a bunch of instances of things in a file
If say I have a file called found that has

```
,cat
,dog
,rat
```

And I have a file data that is like

```
1,dog,bird,cat,rat
2,cat,dog
3,bernie,cat,rat
```

By running this command I want to get a file(That I call NotFound) like

```
1,bird,
2
3,bernie
```

Right now I'm thining I could do it in some sort of way like below, but I know this isn't right

```
while read p; do
        cat data | sed "s/$p//g" > NotFound
done < found
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping in shell is an inefficient approach. I would recommend something like:

```
sed 's/^/s|/;s/$/||g/' found | sed -f - data > notfound
```

In other words, convert the patterns into a single `sed` program and run it against the data file.

Answer (score 0):

Inline editing of `sed` will come handy here as you will keep modifying same file for each line in `found` file:

```
while read -r p; do 
    sed -i "s/$p//g" data
done < found

# check output

cat data
1,bird
2
3,bernie
```